# Uncaught TypeError: Method Promise.prototype.then called on incompatible receiver #<Promise> at Proxy.then (<anonymous>)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-components, sanity

Been trying to fix this for a while and it's becoming quite annoying, help would be really appreciated.

## Context

- using sanity.io cms and I think the error may come from client.js, where the client is created to fetch data from sanity.io
- using nextjs 13
- just moved src related folders into a src folder I created and then added absolute imports
- when refreshing the page the site loads for a splite second then the error shown bellow pops up.
- using styled-components

  [Console error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7E0i.png)
  [client.js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TS5E.png)
  [nextjs error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANbX2.png)

I expected my Next.js app to load my index page without any errors but instead got a TypeError that  I can't reslove after many Google searches

Comment: I got the same error, using Next13, prisma, apollo, trying to fetch data from mongodb